# Доступ к компьютеру, при динамическом ip?

Tags: сеть

Как получить бесплатный ip / доменное имя для перенаправления на мой компьютер? Нужно создать my.site.com, чтобы все запросы приходили ко мне на компьютер, а у меня динамический ip. DynDNS и подобные пробовал - что-то не разберусь, что и как настраивать.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать доступ.

Comment: Бесплатные белые IP-адреса провайдеры вряд ли раздают, равно как и регистраторы доменные имена дарят, хотя со вторыми можно поискать варианты. Если сайт реальный хотите, купите хостинг недорогой и на нем экспериментируйте, если удаленный доступ к компьютеру нужен, поставьте hamachi какой или ему подобные

Answer (score 1):

Ответ здесь: https://toster.ru/q/222140

> Можете попробовать https://ngrok.com/. Одна команда: ngrok http 80
>
> и вам напишут, по какому адресу вы теперь видны интернету, адрес будет
>   вида 92832de0.ngrok.io

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас динамический IP,  с вероятностью 99% вы не доступны для внешнего мира и скрыты за [NAT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT) :) Тоесть вы не можете выступать в роли сервера. Тем не менее выход в интернет у Вас есть, а значит решением может послужить  просто хранить ваши данные на my.site.com, а на вашем компьютере создать программу которая будет заходить и проверять раз в миниту не пришло ли чего.

Comment: Как раз в локалках, *за NAT*, меняющиеся в самом деле IP (≠ DHCP) имеют место лишь в на коленке сделанных сетках с пластмассовым маршрутизатором, но ни как ни в серьёзных домовых сетях или ISP. Кстати, многие IP, выдаваемые по DHCP и в Интернете, сохраняются неизменными месяцами (а то и годами), особенно в случае постоянной работы абонентского устройства.  
  
Не слушайте эту некомпетентную улыбчивую ахинею, дорогой @Rakzin Roman. Я бы ещё что-нибудь посоветовал, где и как спрашивать, но боюсь, что отцы сайта обидятся.

Comment: Incnis Mrsi,  а можно конретно в чем тут ахинея? Я сказал что сам localhost скрытый за NAT(без танцев с бубном) не доступен из вне - Вы не согласны? Далее, я предложил создать самостоятельно промежуточный сервер, по факту, который делает тоже что делает ваш ngrok.com - тут в чем ахинея?

Comment: Начиная с «Если у вас динамический IP, с вероятностью 99% вы не доступны для внешнего мира и скрыты за NAT», далее в подробности не особо вдавался. Динамический (реально меняющийся) IP в Интернете — обычная вещь, причём провайдеры (кроме мобильных), как правило, отдают на абонента прямой (белый) IP.

Я админю IRC-чат на протяжении 9 лет, так что уж знаю, о чём пишу.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, по-моему вы просто к словам цепляетесь и не видите сути ответа. Вот у меня дома комп стоит, подключен через роутер с NAT. Он может выступать в роли сервера без тунеля типа ngrok.com? Если нет, то это именно то, что я хотел сказать в своем ответе. Если да, то расскажите как.

Comment: Да, может и из-за NAT выступать как сервер Интернета, если проброшены порты. Вы хотите, чтобы я тут курс прочёл? Напоминаю тему вопроса: **при динамическом ip**, и предлагаю ограничиться ею. Или Вы не понимаете разницы между NAT и динамикой?